# Cannot use import statement outside a module laravel vue inertia ssr

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix, inertiajs

I'm implementing inertia ssr to existing inertia website
I got this error from vue agile
Cannot use import statement outside a module
I looked up in vue agile docs the says that I have to do this to work with ssr

ssr support

[image: 1]

How can I implement this in laravel mix

Answer (score 0):

I used client only package to continue on
duannx/vue-client-only

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).